# MVC5 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. while updating a record

Tags: model-view-controller

I have done something similar in the past where it updates the table based on an id. Here is the code worked for me in the past but its returning null error.

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
    public ActionResult TestUpdate()
    {
     int id = 3; // this is the FK which exists on the Transactions table. 
     var results = db.StoreTransactions.Find(id);
     if(results != null)
     {
         results.TransStatus = "Completed";
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
    }
```

It appears that results is null but i verified that the record #3 exists. To simply the code below I hard-coded.

I just want to update the results.TransStatus to "Completed". 
Can anyone help please. Thank you!

**----------------- UPDATE ---------------------**

I found out that **Find()** does not work with **foreign keys(FK)**. I hard-coded PK and its no longer Null.

However, I'm still not able to update the table to completed. How can I update the table or the transStatus field? Is the code correct? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Is there multiple items in `results`?

Comment: Is your db context null?

Comment: Things to check: Are you sure it crashes after checking for null, or could the db variable or its StoreTransactions property be null instead? Perhaps the db variable isn't initialized properly yet?

Comment: I updated my post with an update the issue had to do with Find() not liking the FK key. The null issue is gone but I am still not able to update the table.

Comment: What is the new error you are getting?

Comment: No errors. Acts as if everything is fine.  I think I need this statement  **db.Entry(results).State = EntityState.Modified**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The **db.Entry(results).State = EntityState.Modified** was missing. I still don't understand how or why the same code worked on my previous project.